# Is there a closed form solution for the following optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I have the following optimization problem in $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & u^T x - c \sqrt{x^TAx}\\ \text{subject to} & \sum_{i} x_i = 1\\ & x_i \geq 0\end{array}$$

where positive semidefinite $n \times n$ matrix $A$, vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and scalar $c \in \mathbb{R_{+}}$ are given.

Is there a closed form solution? If so, can someone please show how to derive it?

---

I am trying to solve a RL research problem which results in the above-mentioned optimization problem. I am able to get the solution using  gurobi solver which uses interior-point methods for socp but I was hoping there is a closed form solution to this problem.

Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: x is the optimization variable, u, c and A are given.

Comment: Updated it. sorry!

Comment: How can you solve optimization problems with quadratic constraints using linear programming? I am curious.

Comment: Won't the optimal solution  change if I just square it? And I meant, I was able to solve it using gurobipy's quadratic optimization solver.

Comment: do you know if $c > 0 ??$

Comment: Yes, c > 0. Corrected it